# No action execute in struts2 form when try submit him

Tags: forms, struts2

When i click a submit button in my form (struts2), no action gets executed. What could be wrong with this files?

`struts.xml`:

```
        ...<action name="EditMessageAction"
            class="action.content.EditMessageAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/messages/message.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="SaveEditedMessageAction"
            class="action.content.SaveEditedMessageAction">
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/pages/messages/message.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/pages/messages/messagesFirstPosition.jsp</result>       
    </action>...
```

`message.jsp`:

```
            <s:form id="saveEditedUserForm" action="SaveEditedUserAction" theme="simple">
            <h1>Edycja komunikatu</h1>
            <div>
                Id: <b><s:property value="id"/></b>
            </div>
            <div>
                <s:label for="dateFrom" value="Od:*"/>
                <s:textfield id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" required="true"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <s:label for="dateTo" value="Do:*"/>
                <s:textfield id="dateTo" name="dateTo" required="true"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <s:label for="linkChecked" value="Link?"/>
                <s:checkbox id="linkChecked" name="linkChecked" value="true" cssClass="linkChecked"/>
            </div>
            <div class="linkDiv">
                <s:label for="link" value="Link:*"/>
                <s:textfield id="link" name="link"/>
            </div>
            <div class="redirectActionDiv">
                <s:label for="redirectAction" value="redirectAction:*"/>
                <s:textfield id="redirectAction" name="redirectAction"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <s:label for="typeDth" value="DTH:"/>
                <s:checkbox id="typeDth" name="typeDth"/>
            </div>
            <div>

                <s:label for="typeMvno" value="MVNO:"/>
                <s:checkbox id="typeMvno" name="typeMvno" cssClass="typeMvno"/>
                <div class="typeMvnoDiv">
                    <s:label for="subTypeMvnoPostpaid" value="PostPaid:"/>
                    <s:checkbox id="subTypeMvnoPostpaid" name="subTypeMvnoPostpaid"/>
                    <s:label for="subTypeMvnoPrepaid" value="PrePaid:"/>
                    <s:checkbox id="subTypeMvnoPrepaid" name="subTypeMvnoPrepaid"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <s:label for="typeDvbt" value="DVBT:"/>
                <s:checkbox id="typeDvbt" name="typeDvbt"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <s:label for="active" value="Aktywny:"/>
                <s:checkbox id="active" name="active"/>
            </div>
            <div>
<s:submit/>
            </div>
        </s:form>
```

and `SaveEditedMessageAction.java`:

```
package pl.cyfrowypolsat.ebok.bm.action.content;

import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import pl.cyfrowypolsat.ebok.bm.action.BaseAction;
import pl.cyfrowypolsat.ebok.bm.consts.SessionParameters;
import pl.cyfrowypolsat.ebok.bm.ejb.IMessages;
import pl.cyfrowypolsat.ebok.bm.ejb.bean.MessageBean;
import pl.cyfrowypolsat.ebok.bm.utils.EJBLocator;

public class SaveEditedMessageAction extends BaseAction{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(SaveEditedMessageAction.class);

    private int id;

    private Date dateFrom;
    private Date dateTo;

    private String link;
    private String header;
    private String redirectAction;

    private boolean typeDth;
    private boolean typeMvno;
    private boolean typeDvbt;
    private boolean subTypeMvnoPostpaid;
    private boolean subTypeMvnoPrepaid;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean linkChecked;

    public String execute() {
        LOG.info("Enter: execute(). " + dateFrom + " " + link);
        MessageBean sessionMessageBean = (MessageBean) sessionParameters.get(SessionParameters.MESSAGE_EDIT);

        if(sessionMessageBean != null) {
            IMessages messagesEJB = EJBLocator.getMessages();

            sessionMessageBean.setDateFrom(getDateFrom());
            sessionMessageBean.setDateTo(getDateTo());
            sessionMessageBean.setLinkHref(getLink());
            if(linkChecked){
                sessionMessageBean.setHtml(generateMessageHtmlLink(getLink(), getHeader()));
                sessionMessageBean.setRedirectAction("NULL");
            } else {
                sessionMessageBean.setRedirectAction(getRedirectAction());
                sessionMessageBean.setHtml(generateMessageWithoutLink(getHeader()));
            }
            sessionMessageBean.setTypeDth(booleanToInt(isTypeDth()));
            sessionMessageBean.setTypeMvno(booleanToInt(isTypeMvno()));
            sessionMessageBean.setSubTypeMvnoPostpaid(booleanToInt(isSubTypeMvnoPostpaid()));
            sessionMessageBean.setSubTypeMvnoPrepaid(booleanToInt(isSubTypeMvnoPrepaid()));
            sessionMessageBean.setTypeDth(booleanToInt(isTypeDth()));
            sessionMessageBean.setAktywny(booleanToInt(isActive()));

            messagesEJB.updateMessage(sessionMessageBean);
        }
        LOG.info("Exit: execute()");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDateFrom() {
        return dateFrom;
    }

    public void setDateFrom(Date dateFrom) {
        this.dateFrom = dateFrom;
    }

    public Date getDateTo() {
        return dateTo;
    }

    public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
        this.dateTo = dateTo;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getRedirectAction() {
        return redirectAction;
    }

    public void setRedirectAction(String redirectAction) {
        this.redirectAction = redirectAction;
    }

    public boolean isTypeDth() {
        return typeDth;
    }

    public void setTypeDth(boolean typeDth) {
        this.typeDth = typeDth;
    }

    public boolean isTypeMvno() {
        return typeMvno;
    }

    public void setTypeMvno(boolean typeMvno) {
        this.typeMvno = typeMvno;
    }

    public boolean isTypeDvbt() {
        return typeDvbt;
    }

    public void setTypeDvbt(boolean typeDvbt) {
        this.typeDvbt = typeDvbt;
    }

    public boolean isSubTypeMvnoPostpaid() {
        return subTypeMvnoPostpaid;
    }

    public void setSubTypeMvnoPostpaid(boolean subTypeMvnoPostpaid) {
        this.subTypeMvnoPostpaid = subTypeMvnoPostpaid;
    }

    public boolean isSubTypeMvnoPrepaid() {
        return subTypeMvnoPrepaid;
    }

    public void setSubTypeMvnoPrepaid(boolean subTypeMvnoPrepaid) {
        this.subTypeMvnoPrepaid = subTypeMvnoPrepaid;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isLinkChecked() {
        return linkChecked;
    }

    public void setLinkChecked(boolean linkChecked) {
        this.linkChecked = linkChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure there is no action execution? have u looked at the colsole out put, might be some validation or other error blockinng the execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action is targeting `SaveEditedUserAction`, not `SaveEditedMessageAction`.